# Explore Free Form report in Google Analytics

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

I am trying to generate a report using Google Analytics Explore tab using Free Form technique. Few weeks ago I could use Message name, stream name and time to see all the notification name, platform and total no of click. I exported the same to excel file.

[image]

but today when I tried to generate the same I couldn't find "Message Name" dimension. Is this field removed from pre defined/custom dimensions from GA? or am I doing something wrong?

My main purpose is to get all list of notifications sent via Firebase.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you excluded the obvious issues like using the too-fresh data, the proper way to debug it is to export the data into a sample BQ table, then conduct exactly the same analysis that you're trying to conduct in GA4's explorer. From there, if your issue is with explorer's filters, you will quickly see it.

If, however, you're able to see your event properties in BQ, but not able to get the explorer to display them... Well, Google likely saved quite a lot of money on GA4. UA was pretty expensive. GA4 now introduces all these amazing features like data retention limits, properties' values cardinality bugs, odd inconsistencies between explore's reports and default reports and so on.

For now, the best way to really access your data minus all the artificial limitations of GA4 is to ETL your data from there either through the [reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4) or [exporting it to BQ](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9823238?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article).